# How to call php function on submit on the same page while action redirects to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a problem. I want to execute a php function on submit but the php function HAS to be on the same page because of a multi dimensional array foreach loop. So in easy terms input type="submit" action="post only $orderid to ideal.php" onclick="phpFunction on same page"

Here is my code:

```
$total =0;
$b = 0;
$items = array();
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
{
    $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
    $pid = $cart_itm["product_code"];
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID = '".$pid."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($results)) {
$naam = $row["ProductName"];
$liters = $row["ProductLiters"];
$kleur = $row["ProductColor"];
$product_price = $row["ProductPrice"];
$beschrijving = $row["ProductDescription"];
$image = $row["ProductImage"];
$merk = $row["SupplierID"];
}
    $items[] = array('pid' => $pid, 'qty' => $product_qty);
    $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty);
    $total = ($total + $subtotal);
?>

<div class="'.$bg_color.'">
    <h1 class="ptitel" id="ptitel"><?= $naam ?></h1>
    <p class="prijs" id="prijs">&euro;<?= $product_price ?> x <?= $product_qty ?></p>
    <p class="verzenden">Geen verzendkosten binnen Nederland</p>
    <p id="pinfo"><?= $beschrijving ?></p>
<div id="liter">
<p class="text">Liters:  <?= $liters ?></p>
</div>
<div id="kleur">
<p class="text">Kleur:  <?= $kleur ?></p>
  </div>
    </div>

    <?php
}
?>
    </div>
            <div class="left">
<?php
---------THIS HAS TO BE EXECUTED-----------
$orderid = mt_rand(100000,900000);
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Bestellingen (pid, qty, orderid) VALUES         ('".$value['pid']."', '".$value['qty']."', '".$orderid."')");
}
------------------END----------------------


?>
    <form method="post" action="test.php">
        <input type="text" name="realname" id="name" placeholder="Volledige naam" required/>
        <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" required/>
        <input type="text" name="adres" id="adres" placeholder="Straatnaam+huisnummer" required/>
        <input type="text" name="plaats" id="plaats" placeholder="Plaats" required/>
        <input type="tel" name="telefoon" id="telefoon" placeholder="Mobiel nummer" required/>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@voorbeeld.com" required/>
        <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Heeft u wat te vertellen?"></textarea>
        <input type="text" name="discount" id="discount" placeholder="Kortingscode"/>

        <input type="submit" name="betaal" class="knop" value="BETALEN &euro;<?= $total ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: When the user has pressed any submit button, the php instance that served that html document is most likely long done, shut down and garbage collected. Keep in mind: php->on the server, html/javascript->on the client and those two only (by default) communicate through http request exchanges and only the output of php scripts is sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. you can use ajax to post form date to any page.

## 2. you can use js to update action in form tag according to you convenience.

Extra suggestion : use tag `<?php ?>`